# What is the difference between an attribute and a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

The two terms "attribute" and "column" seems to be used interchangeably...but my guess is that a column is the box and an attribute is what goes into the box.

Comment: *attribute* for a *model*, *column* for a *table*

Comment: From database point of view **column** is entire set of results and **attribute** can be the column name. Eg: `select id from some_table;`. Here, `column = list of ids` and `attribute = id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "Column" is a column in a database table whereas "attribute(s)" are externally visible facets of an object.

An "attribute" is for a model and a "column" is for a table in a database.

Here's a schema for a model:

```
create_table "retreats", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.string "tagline"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Here "retreats" is a table in a database with the following columns "title", "tagline", "created_at", "updated_at".

This table has a model Retreat which has attributes "title", "tagline", "created_at" and "updated_at". You can get some more information on attributes on [this](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html) page.

They are similar but they are different because of their context.

edit 1:

A row in a database table is mapped by an object in Rails. The value of the attribute of that object is the value of the column in that row.

As [vojic points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967718/what-is-the-difference-between-an-attribute-and-a-column/44967800?noredirect=1#comment76914867_44967800), a column contains the attribute values for all the objects.

Comment: I would add that "column" may also refer to the complete set of attribute instances within a table. You `SELECT` a column, and the query then returns the value of that column (an attribute) for each of the resulting rows.

Answer (score 0):

**ActiveModel** provides an `attributes API` for convenience which maps instance variables to a hash for ease of use. https://blog.metova.com/rails-5-attributes-api

**ActiveRecord** expands on ActiveModel to map `columns` onto `attributes` automatically, and you can still define custom attributes that do not have columns such as this good example.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html

So in a standard Rails application, ActiveRecord models turn columns into attributes automatically and you can still add your own. You can also have additional ActiveModels that have their own mechanisms for persistence (or not) that use the same attributes API so standard Rails components can pretend it's like an ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that helps:
[image]

From:
Peter Bruce, Andrew Bruce, Peter Gedeck - Practical Statistics for Data Scientists 50+ Essential Concepts Using R and Python-O'Reilly Media (2020)